# D3.js Issue when projection y values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling to plot a line from latitude & longitude in D3, specifically when projecting the y values.

I draw the line using the following code & sample json array.

```js
var json_str = [
{
    "lng1": 53.587,
    "lat1": -2.159,
    "lng2": 53.587,
    "lat2": -2.159,
},
{
    "lng1": 53.587,
    "lat1": -2.159,
    "lng2": 53.587,
    "lat2": -2.157,
}
];

d3.select("#lines").selectAll("line")
.data(json_str)
.enter()
.append("line")
.attr("x1", function (d) { return projection([d.lat1])[0]; })
.attr("y1", function (d) { return projection([d.lng1])[0]; })
.attr("x2", function (d) { return projection([d.lat2])[0]; })
.attr("y2", function (d) { return projection([d.lng2])[0]; })
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-width", 5);
```

When I project the x values, it comes out with the correct value & projects on my map correctly, however when I project Y, using the same functions but on a different field, it gives me crazy values and therefore isn't plotting within the bounds of my SVG. Somewhere in the region of 1299***.

I've used the same function to project x & y values for point data no problem.

```js
d3.select("#points").selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection([d.y, d.x])[0] })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection([d.y, d.x])[1] })
```

EDIT: Marks answer below gets me close, but the projection is still out of shape.

I've created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2i8c8OXsOrzv66QJo0vP) showing my problem, which incorporates Marks answer below. Essentially the 'lines' SVG plots 90 degrees out & I can;t fathom why..

Comment: Your second snippet has the x,y in the wrong order: a projection takes [x,y] values, as noted by Mark below.

Comment: Noted, thank you. Incidentally I actually had my lat/long headers mixed up too, so the two issues actually cancelled each other out. Corrected now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#_projection) states that (bolding mine):

> projection(point)
>
> Returns a new array [x, y] (typically in pixels) representing the projected point of the given point. **The point must be specified as a two-element array [longitude, latitude] in degrees.** May return null if the specified point has no defined projected position, such as when the point is outside the clipping bounds of the projection.

You are passing a singular lat/long values in `return projection([d.lat1])[0];`.  This won't work.

I'd refactor it as:

```
var json_str = [
{
  "lng1": 53.587,
  "lat1": -2.159,
  "lng2": 53.587,
  "lat2": -2.159,
},
{
  "lng1": 53.587,
  "lat1": -2.159,
  "lng2": 53.587,
  "lat2": -2.157,
}
];

d3.select("#lines").selectAll("line")
  .data(json_str)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .each(function(d){
    d.p1 = projection([d.lng1, d.lat1]);
    d.p2 = projection([d.lng2, d.lat2]);
  })
  .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.p1[0]; })
  .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.p1[1]; })
  .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.p2[0]; })
  .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.p2[1]; })
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 5);
```

Comment: Amazing - thank you! 

It is now projecting onto the SVG, but not onto the correct position on my map. I've used the exact same lat/longs from my point data set (as the points should correspond to the line ends). 

Is there a way to plot lines based on a point layer, denoting the start & end node in the JSON, rather than lat/long, (i.e. grabbing the lat /long from the point layer attributes rather than the JSON)? If so, this would help as I'd like to be able to drag the points, and  have the lines move/update with it.

Comment: @stephen.webb you can take screen coordinates and return long/lat pairs with `projection.invert([x,y])`

Comment: I've realised that the projection has come out 90 degrees out, but genuinely no idea why! I'm very new to D3 - what is a good way to upload my code so I can show a working example?

Comment: @stephen.webb, the preferred way would be to update your question with a running stack snippet.  I generally create my working samples in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) then cut/paste into a stack snippet.

Comment: @Mark. Updated with Plunker above

Comment: @stephen.webb, your x and ys are reversed.  Update [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TXPOEp3bo3mSgqWc6TW9?p=preview)

Comment: @Mark Total facepalm, that's the second time. Thank you for your help. Have upvoted but less than 15 rep currently.